# I submit data in the form, but the method cannot be called?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am using the van-button button to submit form data in the foreground. I also use the @submit attribute in the van-form.In @submit, I called my own method, but the defined method cannot be called. What is the reason?

**1.This is the code for the front desk**

```html
<van-form @submit="addHolidayInfo">

  <div style="margin: 16px;">
    <van-button round type="info" native-type="submit">submit</van-button>
    <van-button type="default" round @click="reset">reset</van-button>
  </div>

</van-form>
```

**2.This is my method**

```js
private addHolidayInfo(values: any) {
  console.log("--------------------------");
  Toast.loading({
    message: "...",
    forbidClick: true,
    duration: 0,
  });
  api
    .post("/pm/holidayLog/addHolidayInfo", values)
    .then((Response: any) => {
      const msg = Response.data as Msg;
      if (msg.success) {
        Toast.success(msg.msg);
        this.$router.push("/pm/holiday");
      } else {
        Toast.fail(msg.msg);
      }
    })
    .catch((err: Error) => {
      Toast.fail("！！！");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Probably you should add button type='submit' to trigger submit event.

```html
<van-form @submit="addHolidayInfo">

  <div style="margin: 16px;">
    <van-button type="submit" round type="info" native-type="submit">submit</van-button>
    <van-button type="default" round @click="reset">reset</van-button>
  </div>

</van-form>
```

Comment: Hello, if you add type="submit", it will be the same as type="info". In fact, if I delete type="info", it still has no effect